# Codeigniter routing strange 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with codeigniter routing. 
I can't understand at all, what's wrong.
I have a rule in my routes.php file:

```
$route['multimedia/(:any:)'] = 'multimedia/$1';
$route['multimedia'] = 'multimedia/index';
```

So, if I go to `http://mywebsite.com/multimedia` - all is works well , but if I go to `http://mywebsite.com/multimedia/hello` I get 404 Error.

This is a part of my `multimedia` controller:

```
<?php
class Multimedia extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('multimedia_model');
        $this->load->helper('language');
        $this->load->helper('form');

    }

    public function index(){

    //............This works
    }


    public function hello()
    {
        //..........This not works

    }
}
```

The most strange thing to me, that I have another same rule in routes.php file,

```
$route['popup/(:any)'] = 'popup/$1';
$route['popup'] = 'popup/index';
```

which is works well when I go to `mywebsite.com/popup` and `mywebsite.com/popup/hello`

Anybody, please, help me, what's wrong??

Comment: remove last `:` from the route `$route['multimedia/(:any:)']` and change it to `$route['multimedia/(:any)']`

Comment: why you need these routes rule where those rules are default

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything is works. I didn't notice second `:`!

Comment: Hmm... I am really newbie in CI. I will check documentation about routes again :) Thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['popup'] = 'popup/index';
$route['popup/(:any)'] = 'popup/$1';
```

- (:any) specification should only be called only after all other constraints.
  Try this...